# Conditional format when matching (another sheet) cell in (same workbook)? Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

Also sharing formulas to match
month year
**=Text($A2,"MMM YYYY")=Text($Z$1,"MMM YYYY")**
or year.
**=Text($A2,"YYYY")=Text($Z$1,"YYYY")**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you apply conditional formating from one sheet to another you need to use `INDIRECT`

example:

```
=A1=INDIRECT("Sheet2!A1")
```